# Pktgen failed to load Lua script - User State for CLI not set for Lua

Tags: lua, dpdk

Running Pktgen with Lua scripts generates a failure `User State for CLI not set for Lua`.

The command I'm running is:

```
sudo -E ./usr/local/bin/pktgen --no-telemetry -l 4,6,8,10 -n 4 -a 0000:03:02.0 -m 1024 -- -T -P -m [6:8].0 -f test/hello-world.lua
```

Which gives the following result:

[image: lua error message]

I have set the environment variables `RTE_SDK=/root/Program/dpdk` and
`RTE_TARGET=x86_64-native-linux-gcc`.

The failure comes from `cli.c` ([link to code](https://steel.isi.edu/Projects/SENSS/ACSAC2018/figure7/Setup/pktgen-3.4.5/lib/cli/cli.c)):

```
/**
* Load and execute a command file or Lua script file.
*
*/
int
cli_execute_cmdfile(const char *filename)
{
  if (filename == NULL)
        return 0;

  gb_reset_buf(this_cli->gb);

  if (strstr(filename, ".lua") || strstr(filename, ".LUA") ) {
      if (!this_cli->user_state) {
          cli_printf(">>> User State for CLI not set for Lua\n");
          return -1;
      }
      if (lua_dofile) {
          /* Execute the Lua script file. */
          if (lua_dofile(this_cli->user_state, filename) != 0)
              return -1;
      } else
          cli_printf(">>> Lua is not enabled in configuration!\n");
  } else {
      FILE    *fd;
      char buff[256];

      fd = fopen(filename, "r");
      if (fd == NULL)
          return -1;

      /* Read and feed the lines to the cmdline parser. */
      while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fd))
          cli_input(buff, strlen(buff));

      fclose(fd);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So it would seem `this_cli->user_state` is not set, but how do you set it?

I have looked through the [documentation](https://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli_lib.html) for CLI, but it doesn't mention setting any user state from what I can see.

### Update:

The suggested solution seems like it could be a step in the right direction as it can now find the Lua library, but I'm still receiving the same error after running `meson -Denable_lua=true build`, `ninja -C build` and then `ninja -C build install` followed by `sudo -E ./usr/local/bin/pktgen --no-telemetry -l 4,6,8,10 -n 4 -a 0000:03:02.0 -m 1024 -- -T -P -m [6:8].0 -f test/hello-world.lua`

Perhaps it has something to do with `Run-time dependency lua found: NO`?

[image: runtime lua no]

When running `make install` in `lua-5.4.4` it returns:
[image: lua-5.4.4]

Comment: How did you get the binary?

Comment: `user_state` is set at line 379 of [pktgen-main.c](https://steel.isi.edu/Projects/SENSS/ACSAC2018/figure7/Setup/pktgen-3.4.5/app/pktgen-main.c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user_state` is set in pktgen-main.c, but within a `#ifdef LUA_ENABLED` section.

Looking at `meson_options.txt`, which is at the base directory of a pktgen extraction, it contains:

```
option('enable_lua', type: 'boolean', value: false, description: 'Enable Lua support')
```

That means that you must enable Lua support when building (*after installing dependencies, as shown below*):

```
meson -Denable_lua=true build
```

This is going to require a few more dependencies, so you may have to install them, e.g. in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

And then installing Lua - I had to install it from source as per the [instructions](https://www.lua.org/download.html), because installing it with Ubuntu's package manager **apt** didn't give me the library that was needed:

```
curl -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.4.4.tar.gz
tar zxf lua-5.4.4.tar.gz
cd lua-5.4.4
make all test
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! It seems to still not be working correctly. Please see the update section in the question.

Comment: Solution was to run `make clean buildlua` instead of using `meson` and `ninja`